# How to globally catch network errors of apollo and show a useful error message to the user in apollo 1.x

Tags: apollo, apollo-client

Currently, if there's a network error apollo gives a console log like this `Unhandled (in react-apollo) Error: Network error: Failed to fetch`. My question is how to handle this in one place and show a notification to the user?

There are some stack overflow answers which show us how to handle this component wise and in Apollo 2.0. I need a way to handle this for the whole app in Apollo 1.4.

I tried to use afterware like this and it did not work:

```
const logErrors = {
  applyAfterware({ response }, next) {
    if (!response.ok) {
      response
        .clone()
        .text()
        .then((bodyText) => {
          console.error('Network Error:');
          next();
        });
    } else {
      response
        .clone()
        .json()
        .then(({ errors }) => {
          if (errors) {
            console.error('GraphQL Errors:', errors.map(e => e.message));
          }
          next();
        });
    }
  }
};

networkInterface.useAfter([logErrors]);
```

Comment: Did you referred to this link? https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/1692 looks like the solution provided by @jazzdragon and to this post https://dev.to/andre/react-apollo-an-approach-to-handle-errors-globally-jg ?